# Python script stopping before completion

Tags: python

I'm  Not sure what I'm doing. Why does this stop after asking for Oustanding balance?

```
x=raw_input('Outstanding Balance:');
y=raw_input('Annual Interest Rate:');
z=raw_input('Monthly Interest Rate:');
a=(x*z)
b=((y/12)*x)
c=(a-b)
d=(x-c)
print ("Minimum monthly Payment:"+(a));
print ("Interest Paid:"+ (b));
print ("Principal Paid:"+(c));
print ("Remaining balance:"+(d))
```

Comment: Are any errors displayed?

Comment: It's stopping because it's waiting for your input.

Comment: You don't need semicolons in Python...?

Comment: @louis, no you don't need semicolons in Python. Its a blessing or a curse, but python delimits by indentation level and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

[raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) waits for user-input so it would appear to have stopped running. You can type in some input and hit return for it to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the input to `int` before doing arithmetic operations on them. Modify it as shown below.

```
x=int(raw_input('Outstanding Balance:'))
y=int(raw_input('Annual Interest Rate:'))
z=int(raw_input('Monthly Interest Rate:'))
a=x*z
b=((y/12)*x)
c=(a-b)
d=(x-c)
print ("Minimum monthly Payment:"+str(a))
print ("Interest Paid:"+ str(b))
print ("Principal Paid:"+str(c))

print ("Remaining balance:"+str(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

raw_input() function return a str object, it can't do calculation

Using the build_in function **int()** to turn x to int using **int(x)** and the same as y and z.